# Windows 7 hides file extentions

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 is indicating the file types by icons but the .jpeg .html .txt and what-not portion of the file name is hidden.  How can I reveal it?

Answer (score 9):

Go to Computer from the start menu.
Press Alt+T Then to Folder Options from that menu.
Go to the View Tab.
Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types."
Press Ok.